# Way to supress warning for implicit typecasting from void ** to another **?

Tags: c, gcc

I have a little project that includes handling pointer arrays, and to facilitate that I made a .h file that handles it by doing the operations with void pointers then returns the final product, i.e. the function prototype would be something like `void **ptr_array_add(void **ptr_array, void *new_ptr);`. However, whenever I use this function without explicitly typecasting my pointers to `void **` and back to their original type, gcc throws warnings on the conversion.

Is what I'm doing unsafe? I'm assuming that there must be a reason gcc gives me the warning, but as far as I know, `void **` is identical to any other kind of pointer array since all pointers are 8 bytes long (or however long they are, the point is they are all the same length), and if what I'm doing has no problems, is there a way to supress the warning without having to add 20 characters of typecasting everytime I call these functions?

Thanks

Comment: The behaviour is undefined if you alias pointers as other pointer types , even if the sizes are the same.  The cast just silences the warning, it doesn't make the code safe.

Comment: Casting to and from `void *` is safe.  That safety does *not* extend to `void **`.

Comment: It is generally bad, likely hazardous, to ask how to suppress a warning. The question you should ask is how to write correct, supported code. For that, you must show more context for what you are doing, preferably a [mre].

Comment: When you [edit] your question to react on the comments, please also tell us how many different pointer types you need. Did you consider using a union?

Comment: C allows for object pointers to be implicitly converted to and from type `void *`.  All other conversions involving pointers require a cast.  GCC will perform additional conversions implicitly, but it warns about them (at least under some circumstances).  This is basically a portability warning, and the diagnostic will specify the compiler option that controls that particular warning.  What you are doing is definitely non-conforming and suspicious, but we can't judge the specific risks other than to portability without more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is an array with one pointer after the other, you could probably change the signature to use void*. I make a simple example, writing the new pointer into the second entry of the array and returning the old start of the array.

```
void* ptr_array_add(void* ptr_array, void* new_ptr) {
    void** entries = (void**)ptr_array;
    entries[1] = new_ptr;
    return (void*)entries;
}
```

All the casts are now inside the function.
Your user code would have to keep the array as void*.

If you want to also cast the returned value to a specific type, e.g. int**, that cannot be done automatically.

You would have to create specific wrappers for each type you use.
With a C++ compiler there would be templates.

For C only you could use preprocessor macros to create wrapper functions automatically.

You can (in C) also use an out parameter for the return value, if you may completely change the function signature:

```
// out_ptr_array points to a location, where the result is stored
// in your terminology it would be a void***, but we actually use void*
// in_ptr_array is void**, but we actually use void*
// new_ptr is void*

void ptr_array_add(void* out_ptr_array, void* in_ptr_array, void* new_ptr) {
    void** entries = (void**)in_ptr_array;
    entries[1] = new_ptr;
    void** returnarray = (void**)out_ptr_array;
    *returnarray = entries; // of course we can also return a new/another address to an array
}


// no warnings!
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int* array[3]; // array of pointers to int
    int** arrayptrin; // location of array
    arrayptrin = &array[0];

    int** arrayptrout; // return value of function
    int a = 4;         // value
    int* pa = &a;      // pointer to value for adding

    // call function with parameters
    // where to store result (new array location?), array location, new pointer
    ptr_array_add(&arrayptrout, arrayptrin, pa);

    int* pb = arrayptrout[1]; // read one pointer
    printf("Result: %d\n", *pb); // print, value on pointer location (prints: 4)
}
```

In this example we do not need any casts outside the header function. No warning is issued at all.

Answer (score 1):

The C type system only has one special kind of generic pointer and that is `void*` and only that one. This doesn't apply "recursively" though; there is nothing special with `void**`. So the only type you can assign to a `void**` is another `void**` or the address of a `void*`.

So in order to use the function you posted, you need to declare a `void*` on the caller side, pass that one to the function, then cast the `void*` to the relevant object pointer afterwards:

```
void* tmp;
... ptr_array_add(&tmp, ...);
int* some_other_pointer = tmp; // assuming that the actual data type is indeed int
```

> Is what I'm doing unsafe?

Yes, enforcing invalid pointer conversions by means of a cast to "shut up warnings" will lead to undefined behavior if the pointer is de-referenced as some other type than the one that it actually points at. Specific issues are strict pointer aliasing, pointer sizes and trap representations of pointers, all which can in theory create subtle bugs and crashes.

In practice though, it is likely that most pointers on non-exotic systems have the same size and representation internally. Some libraries like CUDA even uses dirty casts between `void**` and other pointer-to-pointer as part of the API. But there is no support from the C standard guaranteeing any deterministic behavior when you do so.